# Stripe to collect recurring ACH payments with Plaid verification

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I am currently able to collect single ACH payment using Plaid and Stripe. Users on the app make their payments using the bank login models provided by the plaid.

However, I could not find any resources regarding storage of plaid authorized bank tokens so that it can be used later for automated recurring payments.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Plaid has documentation on this available here: https://plaid.com/docs/stripe/

Specifically, step 4 details the endpoint used to exchange the Plaid token and account ID from a Stripe bank account token.

Comment: I have done that part already and was successful in getting single payments. However, for automated recurring payments, can we use the same bank account token?

Comment: @DipendraGurung rather than charging with the token directly, you should probably attach the token to your Stripe customer, and then you could use it to make additional charges. Stripe has documentation ACH charges here: https://stripe.com/docs/ach, specifically how this works with Plaid. Both services have test environments you can use to try out your specific use case.