# Stripe subscription with plaid integration for ACH payment

Tags: java, reactjs, stripe-payments, plaid

I'm trying to add subscription to my application using Stripe. I'm trying to integrate Stripe using its low code [pricing table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table). I already have few users in my system and their bank accounts have been verified through Plaid. I want the users to subscribe and make payments through their bank accounts. As, the accounts are already verified through Plaid, in the Stripe's checkout part I want to be able to select the bank accounts through Plaid.
Is there a way to integrate plaid in Stripe's checkout?
Or, can the payment part be removed from the pricing table?

I've gone through some of the related questions but haven't got the answers to my questions.
[Stripe to collect recurring ACH payments with Plaid verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689183/stripe-to-collect-recurring-ach-payments-with-plaid-verification)

[How to create ACH Payments Using Stripe and Plaid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698094/how-to-create-ach-payments-using-stripe-and-plaid)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Checkout (which is the system Pricing Tables run on) will only prefill saved cards*.
Everything else will be collected each time.

Doesn't help that your ACH tokens are quite old if they were tokenized through Plaid, that's been deprecated for a while.
Your Pricing Tables will be collecting them as Payment Methods now.

If you want to charge your saved tokens without collecting them again, it's possible, but not through Checkout. You'd want to create your Susbcriptions from the backend directly with `off_session=true`:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-off_session

*Specifically, these cards would need to be Payment Method objects with an `email`, `name` and `country` value.

Comment: Stripe's marked the Plaid integration as deprecated, but it's still active and supported. The fact that the token is through Plaid doesn't mean it's old.